# C++ syntax for taking the address of nothrow operator new

Tags: c++, syntax

I would like to take the address of operator (std::nothrow) new.

```
typedef void* (*NewFunc)(size_t);
NewFunc newAddr = &operator new; // OK

typedef void* (*NewFuncNoThrow)(size_t, const std::nothrow_t&);
NewFuncNoThrow newAddrNoThrow = &operator (std::nothrow) new; // Syntax error ')'
```

What should be the right syntax for my last line above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same as the previous one:

```
NewFuncNoThrow newAddrNoThrow = &operator new;
```

`operator new` is an overloaded function name. It will be resolved when needed to convert to a specific type - and that type is `NewFuncNoThrow`, which will guide it to the correct overload.

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/eDhw8j)